# Android: How can I find what opens my app constantly

Tags: android, android-debug

While debugging other application I've noticed that my app constantly starts to run. I've noticed this in the `device` view in eclipse.
How can I debug what code causes it to start? or what process start to run.

Comment: If you close app using "Stop" in the Devices tab, does it restart again?

Comment: @Dimmerg after a while, yes.